# Xcode 9.1 : module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, carthage

I updated xCode from 9.0.1 to 9.1. Everything was ok before, but now, I have this error when I try to build my project (with Carthage) :

`module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.2` (or 4.0.2 for SWIFT 4 users)

Don't need to let you know the module because it doesn't depend on it (because when I comment the import line concerned, the mistake his misplaced to the next import, so for another module).

I tried everything I saw :

- Clean the project
- Clean the Carthage folder
- Clean Derived Data folder:
  `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData`
- Update with Carthage: `carthage update --platform iOS` (with or not `--no-use-binaries`)
- Update Modules
- Build again
- Close and Reopen Xcode
- pray

Carthage (0.26.2) and MacOS (High Sierra) are up to date.

So, my last supposition (as I can read) is that Xcode 9.1 not allow us to use modules not build with Xcode 9.1. So I can come back to Xcode 9.0.1 but I will unable to deliver my project to Xcode 9.1 users. I cannot imagine to wait the update of all the modules. So do you have an idea, please ?

Thanks you !

Comment: Share module name and carthage information, how do you set/integrate module

Comment: Can you check if your Command Line Tools are set to the correct Xcode app? So xcodebuild will resolve correctly. Find out within Xcode or `xcode-select -print-path`

Either set it in Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools or with `xcode-select -switch <path>`

Comment: @Krunal As I said, it doesn't depend on the module because if I comment one import, it's the import of another one who have troubles. My Carthage is up to date. And I integrate module in copying .framework on project, adding in Linked Frameworks and Librairies and using `import ModuleName`

Comment: @J-Bossi So the path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and the command line tools used is `Xcode 9.1 (9B55)` and it's the only choice I have

Comment: @PMIW Carthage decides version of library according version of Xcode and dependency manager (carthage version). May lower version of Xcode needs lower version of librart/module.

Comment: @Krunal so what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to upgrade every framework  you are using to 9.1.

**"As I said, it doesn't depend on the module because if I comment one import, it's the import of another one who have troubles"**

That's because the next one has the exact same problem.  Just replace all your frameworks in the "Embedded Binaries" with versions that have been compiled with 9.1. To prove it to yourself, do it on the first one it complains about, and Xcode will then tell you the second one is now the problem, etc.

Comment: Did I misread the "what's new" with Swift 4/Xcode 9?  For some reason I thought I had read you can have Swift 3 and 4 modules mixed (a 3 that depends on a 4, or a 4 that depends on a 3).  Or, is this true, but you have to recompile everything using Xcode 9 for it to work?

Comment: I had your issue, and what I recommend solved it I don't know if it is possibly a settings issue or a compiler bug.

Comment: @Mozahler So, if I use external modules.. I just have to wait they compiled their module with Xcode 9.1 ?

Comment: I thought you were using Carthage?  If so, running "carthage" update will do that for you.

Comment: String api has breaking changes which you (or 3rd party) will have to fix.

Comment: @Mozahler yes I am, but they don't update their modules.

Comment: Did you try running carthage on the libraries? That should fix the problem. There's nothing to wait for.

Comment: The SnapKit doesn't have any update since last year. I got this compiler error still. I decide remove all SnapKit from my code.